# Ob_end_flush is generating constant errors

Tags: javascript, php, buffer, server-sent-events

I am currently working with Server-Sent Events and I am having a strange issue. As the event goes on, through each iteration I am receiving the following error:

> ob_end_flush(): failed to delete and flush buffer. No buffer to delete
>   or flush in

My code for the Server-Event Server Side is as follows:

```
<?php

  require "connect.php";

  session_write_close();

  header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");

  $savedcount = 0; 
  while (1) {

    // Who's mechanism 
    $query = $mysqli->query("SOME QUERY"); 
    $rowcount = $query->num_rows;

    if ($savedcount != $rowcount) {
       // echo stuff
       $savedcount = $rowcount; // only echo stuff if there is new content
    }

    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(2);
  }

?>
```

I do not completely understand buffers. Also, before you assume that this is terrible practice please know that Server-Sent Events are special. This is a similar script that they show on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#Sending_events_from_the_server). For this reason I am not exactly sure why I am continuously receiving these errors.

Suggestions?

Comment: Before you can send the contents of the buffer, you have to start one using [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php). Also, with while(1) this script will run until the server stops it at the max execution time. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, this is what you need for Server-Sent Events to work properly

Comment: Start the buffer with: `ob_start();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always used this idiom:

```
@ob_flush();@flush();
```

Quoting from p.21 of Data Push Apps With HTML5 SSE: (disclaimer: my book)

> @ is said to be slow. But putting that in context, it adds on the order of 0.01ms to call it twice, as shown here.
>   ...
>   http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c#l290 suggests flush() can never throw an error, so @ on flush() could be dropped, just leaving it on @ob_flush().

http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=main/output.c#l1328 shows the two E_NOTICEs that `ob_flush()` can give.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, the output buffer holds the actual content that will be printed to the page - essentially anything that is echoed or printed.  So in the case that you echo nothing at all, the buffer will be empty, and you will get an error when you try to send nothing with ob_end_flush.  You could just add a check to avoid this error:

```
if (ob_get_length() > 0) {
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
}

sleep(2);
```